# g++ не видит статическую библиотеку

Tags: c++, c, mingw, g++, сборка

Доброго времени суток.

**Задача:** WinAPI + OpenGL + SOIL создать окно, а потом загрузить и вывести  .png картинку.

**Что сделано:** Создал окно, нарисовал в нем несколько примитивов с помощью openGL.

**Что не получается:** собрать проект вместе с SOIL

**На чем и под что пишу:** компилирую и собираю - g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0, код пишу в Notepad++, с g++ работаю из командной строки, ОС - Windows 10.

**Подключаемые библиотеки:** OpenGL изначально присутствовал на компьютере, поэтому необходимость скачать библиотеку возникла только касательно SOIL. Скачал SOIL с официального сайта в виде zip архива. После распаковки открыл папку lib где нашел файл libSOIL.a. Я скопировал этот файл, а также файл SOIL.h в папку где лежат исходники моего проекта.

**Как пытаюсь собрать:** Весь мой собственный исходный код находится в файле main.cpp. В том же каталоге, где лежит main.cpp, лежат файлы SOIL.h и libSOIL.a.

Собираю с пмощью команды g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -mwindows -l opengl32 -I. -l SOIL. Но g++ пишет: s:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSOIL

Тогда решаю указать дерикторию в которой лежит libSOIL.a: g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -mwindows -l opengl32 -I. -L. -l SOIL. Но тогда g++ не может найти openGL и выдает множество сообщений вроде - ./libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'

**Вопрос:** скажите пожалуйста, какие ошибки я допускаю в приведенных командах для g++ и как их исправить?

Comment: `-lopengl32` поставьте после `-lSOIL`

Comment: Спасибо, @Croessmah! Это помогло. Могли бы вы объяснить - какую в данном случае порядок указания имен библиотек играет роль? Если вам не сложно - напишите это в ответе и я укажу его как решение.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в последовательности указания подключаемых библиотек. В комментраиях под вопросом пользователь @Croessmah дал ответ.

Answer (score -1):

в компиляторе флаг -L показывает путь где лежат не стандартные библиотеки